in Angular 2+ , markAsPristine , markAsTouched and markAsDirty, are these methods sync or async?
Can this form named someForm end up with someFormControl control as pristine. Is it happening async, and doing such a thing is bad ?
My question is this: These mark* methods are happening async or synchronous . Can I do consecutive calls ?
this.someForm?.get('someFormControl')?.markAsTouched();
this.someForm?.get('someFormControl')?.markAsPristine();
this.someForm?.get('someFormControl')?.markAsDirty();

I am checking an interminted bug which i think is happening because the form ends up as pristine.
